# Migrating to a different third party push notification service - iOS app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Our iOS app was using a third party service - A in order to send our customers push notifications. There were a few thousand opt ins. We now want to abandon service A and migrate to another third party service - B. The certificates, bundle identifier of the app and all of the app set up remains the same.

Are there any specific steps to make sure that users who opted in while we were using service A are seamlessly migrated over to service B (the device token etc.). Obviously we can't have the user see the prompt to opt in again, but will include the prompt in service B's initialization code.

So, apart from :

- Calling `RegisterForRemoteNotifications`in the AppDelegate (as always)
- Checking for `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` before displaying the user alert to opt in

are there any other steps that need to be performed to complete the transition?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what services A and B are, I once migrated an app from Amazon SNS notifications to Firebase and there are steps to export data from SNS as CSV and import again in Firebase. But likely you have nothing to do in your app.